# CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener inside my custom cursor adapter will not find the correct R.id that the listener is listening from

Tags: android

I am using this code inside the listener onCheckedChanged method to get the R.id. It is usually 3 or 4 rows off.

```
TextView gameN = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_Title);
CharSequence text = gameN.getText();
```

I am thinking it has something to do with how my CustomAdapter is recycling the rows. I am also using the ViewHolder Pattern. Here is the code for my customAdaptor -

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
private int res;
private String mgName;
private String mMfg;
private String mRarity;
private String mLoosePrice;
private String mgYear;
private String mYear_Mfg;
private int mOwned;
private boolean isOwned;
private Switch mySwitch;
private String mID;
private String mIDfinal;
private View v;
private int position = 1;


public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    v = cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.game);
    holder.textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_Title);
    holder.textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_mfg);
    holder.textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rarity_value);
    holder.textView4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.loose_cart_value);
    holder.switch1 = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.owned_switch);
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

//Determines row colors
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bbbbbb"));
        position++;
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7b7b7b"));
        position++;
    }
    if (position > 10) {
        position = 1;
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String mboxArt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Game._id"));
    mboxArt = "a" + mboxArt;
    res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mboxArt, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    mgName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Game.gName"));
    mMfg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.mfg"));
    mgYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.gYear"));
    mYear_Mfg = mMfg + "," + mgYear;
    mRarity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.rarity"));
    mOwned = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("My_Collection_T.cart"));
    mLoosePrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Price_ID_T.lPrice"));
    mID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("My_Collection_T._id"));
    mIDfinal = "'" + mID + "'";

    if (mOwned == 1) {
        isOwned = true;
    } else {
        isOwned = false;
    }
    view.setTag(holder);


    holder.imageView.setImageResource(res);

    holder.textView1.setText(mgName);

    holder.textView2.setText(mYear_Mfg);

    holder.textView3.setText(mRarity);

    holder.textView4.setText(mLoosePrice);

    holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);

    //Listener for owned switch
    mySwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.owned_switch);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();
            TextView gameN = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_Title);
            CharSequence text = gameN.getText();
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                mNewValues.put("cart", 1);
                mNewValues.put("numCart", 1);
                mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, mIDfinal, null);

                ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
                Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                if (c != null) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    dumpCursor(c, sb);
                    String result = sb.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                            result,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                    c.close();
                }
                mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
            } else {
                mNewValues.put("cart", 0);
                mNewValues.put("numCart", 0);
                mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, mIDfinal, null);

                ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
                Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                if (c != null) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    dumpCursor(c, sb);
                    String result = sb.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                            result,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                    c.close();
                }
                mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
            }
        }
    });
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;
    TextView textView4;
    Switch switch1;

    String mBoxArt;
    String mGname;
    String mMfg;

}
}
```

How do I retrieve the correct R.id. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `View v` only in `newView`. I think you need to use `View view` given to you by `bindView`. Make sure `View view` is declared `final` to access it in a callback. By the time your `onCheckChanged` is called, `View v` is most likely the last view in your adapter and therefore the wrong view.

Use `bindView` like so:

```
@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

//Determines row colors
if (position % 2 == 1) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bbbbbb"));
    position++;
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7b7b7b"));
    position++;
}
if (position > 10) {
    position = 1;
}

ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

String mboxArt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Game._id"));
mboxArt = "a" + mboxArt;
res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mboxArt, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
mgName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Game.gName"));
mMfg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.mfg"));
mgYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.gYear"));
mYear_Mfg = mMfg + "," + mgYear;
mRarity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Made_for.rarity"));
mOwned = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("My_Collection_T.cart"));
mLoosePrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Collect_Price_ID_T.lPrice"));
mID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("My_Collection_T._id"));
mIDfinal = "'" + mID + "'";

if (mOwned == 1) {
    isOwned = true;
} else {
    isOwned = false;
}
view.setTag(holder);


holder.imageView.setImageResource(res);

holder.textView1.setText(mgName);

holder.textView2.setText(mYear_Mfg);

holder.textView3.setText(mRarity);

holder.textView4.setText(mLoosePrice);

holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);

//Listener for owned switch
mySwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.owned_switch);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();
        TextView gameN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.game_Title); //Note the difference between v and view
        CharSequence text = gameN.getText();
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
            mNewValues.put("cart", 1);
            mNewValues.put("numCart", 1);
            mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, mIDfinal, null);

            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                dumpCursor(c, sb);
                String result = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
                c.close();
            }
            mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
        } else {
            mNewValues.put("cart", 0);
            mNewValues.put("numCart", 0);
            mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, mIDfinal, null);

            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                dumpCursor(c, sb);
                String result = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
                c.close();
            }
            mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: That was my problem, thanks! Are there any disadvantages for passing in a "final" param?

Comment: You're welcome. If you use `final`, you can only initialize the variable once. After you did `View view = ` you can't use `view = ` anymore. If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it